# Wrap words in tags, keep markup

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

For example I have a string with markup (from html node):

h*e**llo, thi**s i***s d**og

```
"h<em>e<strong>llo, thi</strong>s i</em><strong>s d</strong>og"
```

What is the most correct way to find some words in it (let's say "hello" and "dog"), wrap them in a span (make a highlight) and save all the markup?

Desired output is something like this (notice properly closed tags)

```
<span class="highlight">h<em>e<strong>llo</strong></em></span><strong>,</strong> <em><strong>thi</strong>s<em> i</em><strong>s <span class="highlight"><strong>d</strong>og</span>
```

Looks the same as it should:

h*e**llo******,*** ***thi**s i***s d**og

Comment: 'save all the markup' *where*?

Comment: It's not trivial, and depends by what the browser supports. The best method I know is using [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) object.

Comment: I am not talking about browser highlight, it was just an example. All I need is some html element wrapper around my words

Comment: Given `hel<b>lo world</b>` and the word to wrap is "hello" - what should it return?

Comment: <span class="highlight">hel<b>lo</b></span> <b>world</b> to highlight "hello"

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
//Actual string
var string = "h<em>e<strong>llo, thi</strong>s i</em><strong>s d</strong>og";

//RegExp to cleanup html markup
var tags_regexp = /<\/?[^>]+>/gi;

//Cleaned string from markup
var pure_string = string.replace(tags_regexp,"");

//potential words (with original markup)
var potential_words = string.split(" ");

//potential words (withOUT original markup)
var potential_pure_words = pure_string.split(" ");

//We're goin' into loop here to wrap some tags around desired words
for (var i in potential_words) {

    //Check words here
    if(potential_pure_words[i] == "hello," || potential_pure_words[i] == "dog")

    //Wrapping...
    potential_words[i] = "<span class=\"highlight\">" + potential_words[i] + "</span>";
}

//Make it string again
var result = potential_words.join(" ");

//Happy endings :D
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not really an optimized solution, but still, you know, it works.
I'm sleepy, so optimizing it is by yourself :D

Comment: there is a problem: tags are closed and opened in wrong order: '<span class="highlight">h<em>e<strong>llo,</span>'

Comment: @spacevillain Uhm, didn't notice it but you need to do some clarifications here so I can fix it: **1-** in your original string, </em> is after "s i" but in your corrected string, it's after "llo". **Why**? **2-** If answer to my previous question is based on logic, is there any more logic for rest of your corrected string? **3-** If it's not logic, then perhaps it's a typo, so you should find a way to correct your markup programmatically, then take a look at Chromium project's source, it'll help you to write some sort of markup cleaner/corrector for this purpose.